# ¿Como regresar usando un enlace desde un componente Vue a Ruta web Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify

**Mi componente desde donde quiero enrutar hacia Laravel Observe la pregunta en href  en el script:**
La idea en realidad es devolverme desde el componente Vue a una vista de Laravel. Me he percatado que vue router me permite ir perfectamente de un componente vue a otro componente vue y lo que yo necesito es ir desde un enlace en un componente vue a una vista de laravel que pertenece a una ruta web

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <v-breadcrumbs
          :items="items"
          divider="."
        ></v-breadcrumbs>
      </div>
    
    </template>
    <script>
      export default {
        data: () => ({
          items: [
            {
              text: 'Dashboard',
              disabled: false,
              href: '¿como agrego aquí una ruta web de laravel?',
            },
            {
              text: 'Link 1',
              disabled: false,
              href: 'breadcrumbs_link_1',
            },
            {
              text: 'Link 2',
              disabled: true,
              href: 'breadcrumbs_link_2',
            },
          ],
        }),
      }
    </script>
```